# why does adding a "print" after the cmp, will cause the output to be always "1st input is greater than 2nd"?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

If I enter a value that is supposed to be lesser than the second input, the output will always be "1st input is greater than 2nd".

It would have no issues if I place the "print chr$("Answer:", 10)" before the CMP operator. Could someone help understand this, I'm really confused.

```
.data
    var1 dd 0
    var2 dd 0

.code
start:

here: print chr$("printing a message with loop"), 10
    mov var1, sval(input("Key in 1st num ber: "))
    mov var2, sval(input("Key in 2nd number: "))

    mov eax, var1

    cmp eax, var2

    print chr$("Answer:", 10)

    jg greater
    je equal
    jng notGreater

print chr$("I am here!", 10)

    greater: print chr$("1st input is greater than 2nd", 10)
        jmp termination

    equal: print chr$("1st input is equal to 2nd", 10)
        jmp termination

    notGreater: print chr$("1st input is lesser than 2nd", 10)
        jmp termination

termination: exit
end start
```

Here the actual output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bIAb.jpg

Comment: It would seem that `print` does not preserve the flags register.

Comment: what does it mean exactly?

Comment: It means that you cannot rely on the flags set by `cmp eax, var2` to remain unchanged by `print`.